# print matrix in class using recursion - python

Tags: python, class, recursion

Using Python -I have a class that accepts matrix of numbers and I need to print the matrix using recursion and it prints the first array over and over again. What do I do wrong

This is the code I wrote

```
class Matrix:
    def __init__(self,mtx):
        self.mtx = mtx
        
    def PrintMat(self,mtx):
        if len(self.mtx)==1:
            print(self.mtx[0])
        else:
            print(self.mtx[0])
            self.PrintMat(self.mtx[1:])
            
    def properties(self):
        print(self.mtx)
        
matrix = Matrix(([1,2,3],[2,3,4]))
matrix.PrintMat(matrix)
```

Comment: `PrintMat` never uses the `mtx` argument. It only inspects `self.mtx`, which is the same in every recursive call.

Comment: so how do I pass it the mtx?

Answer (score 0):

The function `PrintMat` uses the class variable instead of its paramater.

Try:

```
def PrintMat(self,mtx):
    if len(mtx)==1:
        print(mtx[0])
    else:
        print(mtx[0])
        self.PrintMat(mtx[1:])
```

Comment: Tried your solution, now the code doesn't work at all :(

Comment: That's probably because the function now actually needs a list as parameter while you're calling it like `matrix.PrintMat(matrix)`  and `matrix` is an object, not a list.
Try `matrix.PrintMat(matrix.mtx)` to pass it's matrix (list) to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be passing a `mtx` argument- use `self.mtx`. Also, you'll run into issues if your matrix is empty (index error) or too long (recursion depth exceeded). Do something like this instead:

```py
def print_matrix(self):
    for row in self.mtx:
        print(row)
```

You may even want to consider just making a `__str__` or `__repr__` method for your class that returns the matrix as a string, so you can print that. Or just use [pprint.pprint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint) to print your matrix on multiple lines if each row is sufficiently long. An example using `pformat`:

```py
from pprint import pformat

class Matrix:
    def __init__(self, mtx):
        self.mtx = mtx

    def __repr__(self):
        return pformat(self.mtx)
```

Comment: Hi
I want to try it without outer libraries

Comment: @JonathanM `pprint` is part of python's standard library.